# Replaces the space with %20 while using css

Tags: css, asp.net

Sorry that the title is not accurate, but there's my problem:
I'm trying to set a background-image using css in code behind, and I want to add to that image a linear-gradient, something like that:

```
Image1.Style["background-image"] = "linear-gradient(toright, rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%), url(URLImage)";
```

but when I run the page, it replaces the space in the code with %20, so it doesn't work `Url(linear-gradient(toright,%20rgba(0,0,0,0.8)%200%,%20rgba(0,0,0,0)%2050%),%20url(........)`

*I'm setting the Image on code-behind aswell

I've tried to use @, but it didn't work
Can someone please help me? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Escaping the spaces with a backslash should work here.

```
Image1.Style["background-image"] = "linear-gradient(toright,\ rgba(0,0,0,0.8)\ 0%,\ rgba(0,0,0,0)\ 50%),\ url(URLImage)";
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it says something about Unrecongnized escape sequance..